# Excel - sort 3 numbers MIN MAX and?

Tags: excel-formula

I have in Excel 3 columns with numbers, lets say x, y and z.
In a fourt column I want to have them sorted and as text concatunated.

Sample

```
Col A, Col B, Col C, Col D

12   , 34    , 26   , 122634 < result

54    , 87   , 54   , 545487
```

I did try using MIN and MAX, but of course how to get the one between.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Have you looked into LARGE & SMALL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use small (or large). The formula would be:

```
=SMALL(A2:C2,1)&SMALL(A2:C2,2)&SMALL(A2:C2,3)
```

where the 1st argument is the range of numbers and the 2nd argument is the "position" on the sorted range.

Comment: Or in Office365: `=TEXTJOIN(,1,SMALL(A1:C1,SEQUENCE(3)))`, or prior: `=TEXTJOIN(,1,SMALL(A1:C1,{1,2,3}))` last one confirmed with `ctrl+shift+enter`